# How to achive gradient in @react-native-community/slider

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-community

I m using [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/slider) for the slider and I want to achieve gradient within the slider as shown in the image below how do I get this?

[image]

Comment: Ready made package for you https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-slider-color-picker?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you cont pass gradient color as props. But you can pass component as the slider pip so
Create react native component from svg image by convert it using any online converter and push it as props.